# jQuery UI tabs: how to make different tabs styles per one site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

[jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is a wonderful instrument. But as I see it has the same style on all pages through one site.

But I wont to change it style from page to page. I think it is possible to do adding extra classes to jQuery code. But I do not know how to do that.

I need on one page tabs have border (I mean border over tabs headers and it's content, as default) and on another not.

Could anyone help me implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also

Comment: Please read this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to your tabs wrapper and style it in the CSS.

```
<div id="tabs" class="about-page">
<div id="tabs" class="contact-page">
```

*CSS*

```
#tabs.about-page {
   border: 1px solid red;
}

#tabs.contact-page {
   color: blue;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

...and so on.

In your script tag, you should still call it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```