# Add css file dynamically to ckeditor javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to add a css file dynamically to the ckeditor. The css file is uploaded using an uploader on the same page as the editor and oncomplete I want to add the css file to the ckeditor using the below code,

```
function addToEditor(editorName, fileUrl)
if(fileUrl != '')
    {
        var randomNumber = Math.random();

        alert(_gWebDocRoot + fileUrl + '?v='+ randomNumber);

        CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].config.contentsCss = _gWebDocRoot + fileUrl + '?v='+ randomNumber;
    }
}
```

But the above code does not work, please help me solve this issue.
Regards,

Neha

Comment: Please add this in jsfiddle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting external css to ck editor dynamically in djbrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081472/setting-external-css-to-ck-editor-dynamically-in-djbrowser)

Answer (score -3):

```
var doc = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.$; // shortcut
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "http://my.little.pony.net/Your.css"
  }).appendTo($(doc).find("head"));
```

Comment: @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ, Doesn't matter about the copy paste. Solution should be work.

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Flag the question as a *duplicate* if it has been already answered elsewhere.

Comment: I tried the below code,

var doc = CKEDITOR.instances.editorName.document.$; // shortcut
   $("<link/>", {
      rel: "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: _gWebDocRoot + fileUrl + '?v='+ randomNumber
     }).appendTo($(doc).find("head"));

But it does not work. Gives the below error,

CKEDITOR.instances.editorName is undefined

Comment: Change some editor name. In your case you are passing dynamically. Something like  CKEDITOR.instances[editorName]

Comment: I tried this,
var doc = CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].document.$; also 
var doc = CKEDITOR.instances[editorName];
Does not give error but does not add the css file to the editor also.