# Having multiple view options on web page?

Tags: jquery, layout, grid-layout

I'm creating a blog layout for personal use and I'm looking for a starting point or help in finding something that will give the viewer different options on how they want to view the content (a full view or grid option).

[example](http://lookbook.nu/) - notice on the right side of navigation bar that's placed above the content? It has a dropdown menu that says "Full View" and then you have the option to use the "Thumbnail View" and it switches to a grid layout.

The only thing that I've used before that's similar is the MixItUp Jquery plugin but I'm not sure if that's what would work for this since it's not a gallery. I'm also not sure if this action has a specific name but any insight would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I believe the site you used as an example simply has two different views and uses anchor tags that redirects to that specific page if clicked.  Why not do something similar?

Comment: Alright, thanks! I think that may just be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

The website in question seems to just redirect to different views via anchor tags.  Alternatively, if you just want to style the page slightly differently, you could load different style sheets with jQuery.  If interested, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also).