# Link Existing HTML and CSS files into Meteor Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I want to integrate an lengthy already made form possessing both a css and html file into my existing meteor project. How would I do something like that? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<template name = "premadeForm">
    somehow link with other html and css files
</template>
```

and then integrate that template into my application:

```
{{> premadeForm}}
```

I could be going about this in an unreasonable way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just copy/paste the HTML into your `premadeForm` template.  CSS file can be dropped into the client folder and it will just work.

If you need to keep it separate you can load them yourself using the 'public' folder method that @p4bloch described.  Putting them in the public folder makes them accessible from the client but doesn't automatically push them down.  So you then need to load them yourself using an ajax call:

Assuming the files are directly in the 'public' folder:

*Load HTML on-demand:*

```
$.get( "yourform.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

*Load CSS on-demand:*

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "yourcss.css"
}).appendTo("head");
```

Source: [Load external css file like scripts in jquery which is compatible in ie also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just copy and pasting. However the new .css file messes of my previous set classes, such as input is defined different for the premadeform than for my original app. Is there a way to keep the css defined only for the premadeform template?

Comment: No easy way that I know of.  Best to just namespace your css definitions: ".premadeform-header { font-size:1.2em; }"

Comment: Say in my premadeform I have modified the .css of the <table> tag. However I only want the changes to only apply to the premadeform. Should `.premadeform-table { }` work for the css definition? Would I also have to change the html to `<table class='premadeform'>`? I am confused about how the implementation would work.

Comment: @Nate, any css class that is unique to the premadeform would be sufficient.  You can also apply more than one class to an element.  So for example, your table could be `<table class='premadeform target123'>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the css file under the **public** folder, for example at **/public/main.css** you can link to it as **yourapp.tld/main.css**

And then you would have to create a link tag on the template with the src pointing to that URL. I am not sure if you will be able to load it in the header, but maybe in the body works fine for what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This only solves half of the problem. The question of how to include the existing HTML file(s) still remains.