# Wordpress: Is there a way to move stylesheets from head to body?

Tags: wordpress

I want to move theme stylesheets from head section to body section, for example:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-main-css-css'
      href='//www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/css/foundation.css' 
      type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I want to move this link to the body section, but don't know how.

Comment: Why would you even think of that? CSS links are always in the head of a page!

Comment: https://www.webdesignby.com/programming/wordpress-hook-after-body-tag/

Comment: @Dadani: Just for testing purpose nothing else. :)

Comment: @Fil: Thanks for the link. Its helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, for example:

1. As simple as this:

```html
<link href=".../yourstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Mind the difference, you don't put rel="stylesheet/css", just rel="stylesheet"

2. JS way:

```js
loadCSS = function(href) {

  var cssLink = $("<link>");
  $("head").append(cssLink); //IE hack: append before setting href

  cssLink.attr({
    rel:  "stylesheet",
    type: "text/css",
    href: href
  });

};
```

Usage:

```
loadCSS("loadCSS(".../yourstylesheet.css");");
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556622/6134447

But I second Dadani's question: why would you do that? :)

Comment: Only for testing. :)

Comment: What about performance, you can use that as a substitute for 'defer' in old browsers