# Impossible to link style sheets with window.open without url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon closing a jQuery dialog, I use a $.ajax call to retrieve data from a server. In the call back, I pass the returned data the usual way to a function, like so:

```
success: function (result) { displayPage ( result);}
```

This function means to display in a pop-up window the argument data and manage these through miscellaneous jQuery commands along with CSS style sheets:

```
function displayPage (result) // analytical comments included
{
    // (1) this block does not work: testPage shows, not writing occurs-----------
 /*
    var myWindow = window.open('../innout/testPage.php', "_blank", "height=1000, width=1300,top=50,left=150"),
        myPage = myWindow.document.body,
        txt = 'some Text';

    $('#div1', myPage).html (txt);// neither this is operative…
    myPage.write (txt); // nor this
  */

    // (2) this block works, but no structure, no style sheets: -----------------
  /*
    var myWindow = window.open('', "_blank", "height=1000, width=1300,top=50,left=150"),
        myPage = myWindow.document.body,
        txt = 'some Text';

    myWindow.document.write (txt);
  */

    // (3) this block works, but SYNCHRO problem: -----------------

    var myWindow = window.open('', "_blank", "height=1000, width=1300,top=50,left=150"),
        myPage = myWindow.document.body,
        txt = 'some Text',
        pageStruct = "<html>"
                    + "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Landscape</title></head>"
                    + "<body bgcolor='pink'><div id='div1'</div></body>"
              // or + "<body style='background-color: pink'><div id='div1'</div></body>"
                    + "</html>",
        styleLinks = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../innout/DossierCSS/globalRules.css'>"; 

      // Let's try now to link style sheets: 

        $(styleLinks).appendTo(myPage); // INEFFECTIVE
          // or:
        $(styleLinks).appendTo(myWindow.document.head); // INEFFECTIVE
         // What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also
        $("<link/>",
        {
           rel: "stylesheet",
           type: "text/css",
           href: "../innout/DossierCSS/globalRules.css"
        }).appendTo("head") // INEFFECTIVE. Also tried: (myWindow.document, "head")

        $(pageStruct).appendTo(myPage); // works

        $(myPage).attr ('bgcolor', 'pink'); // without it, 'original' bgcolor attribute inoperative !

        $('#div1', myPage).toggleClass ('violet');// INEFFECTIVE — .violet defined in globalRules.css as color:purple

        $('#div1', myPage).css ( {"color": "purple" }); // works

        $('#div1', myPage).html (txt); // works
}
```

My first approach was to pass `window.open` a URL, i.e. testPage.php —a very simple one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Landscape</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Way (1) allows no writing, while ways (2) and (3) do.

Way (3) seems satisfactory but it is not: I am unable to link css style sheets to the page. I have tried to no avail two different methods, one of which was detailed in an SOE post (quoted). Also, adding either in-line style or html formatting at the `pageStruct` level is ineffective.

It seems that `<link>` instructions cannot be passed to `<head>` because file headers have already been sent. Through way (1), 'modification' instructions briefly flicker in the background then get overridden by the `testPage.php` contents: apparently, the processing of `window.open` takes place *after* the rest of the code: **synchro problem !**

Notice: a) I also tried to delay the DOM-modification instructions with setTimeOut —unsuccessfully; b) I cannot define a static structure in a page to be loaded for I have to handle dynamic elements.

How then do I link my style sheets in good synchronization?

Comment: I will give it a go and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: That actually was the cause of the malfunctionning. 1) If you will, I suggest you delete your comment and re-post it as a formal answer: I will vote it up and it may help other SO users; if you will not I shall vote your comment up anyhow. 2) If you are interested in a part-time job opportunity, let me know how I can get in touch with and I shall send you further details.

Comment: ;-) glad it helped. As you may have noticed in my comment I don't have too much time right now to write a formal answer, but I will in the evening. And for the part time job, the reason I don't have time is that I've got a full time job, so I'll kindly refuse this :-)

Comment: Very good, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not how you do add the stylesheet in the new document (should be in the `<head>` btw), but it's `href` attribute.

Currently, you've set it to `"../innout/DossierCSS/globalRules.css"`, which is a "relative URI", and it is relative to the current `document.baseURI` path.

Since you do set the `window.open()`'s URL parameter to `_blank`, the `baseURI` of the new document will be set by default to `about:blank`. Then, when converted to an absolute URL, your relative URL will point to an invalid URL.

The solution to this is either to set your `<style>`'s `href` attribute to an absolute URL (`"http://yoursite.net/innout/DossierCSS/globalRules.css"`) or to use a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element, with its `href` attribute set to `"http://yoursite.net/someDirectory/"`.
This later approach will set the document's `baseURI` to its `href` attribute's value, making all relative URLs relative to this new URL. Note that it should be placed in the document before any other element pointing to an external resource.