# How do I load bootstrap in a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am running a code that scrapes a form and then opens a new browser tab with the data using the format: fieldID, fieldLabel, filedValue

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#helpdesk_ticket_submit').on('click', function(e){
  submitText = "<table class='table'>"
  submitText += `  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">fieldID</th>
                      <th scope="col">fieldLabel</th>
                      <th scope="col">fieldValue</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>`
  
  jQuery('#new_helpdesk_ticket input, #new_helpdesk_ticket select, #new_helpdesk_ticket textarea').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = jQuery(this);
        if (input.prev().is('textarea'))
          if (input.attr('class').indexOf('hide') >= 0) 
            return;
        let label =  extractLabelText(input.attr('id')) //extrenal function to get the label of the field
        submitText += "<tr><td>" + input.attr('id') + "</td><td>" + label  + "</td><td> " + input.val() + "</td></tr>"
    }
    
  );

  window.open().document.write(submitText);
```

there is nothing wrong with the code. My question  is  when I do `window.open().document.write(submitText);` how can I format the table with bootstrap?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also is probably close to what you want to do.

Comment: What if you started submitText out with a link to bootstrap css delivered from a CDN? Would that accomplish what you want?  `submitText = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">'`