# Como inicializar manualmente o plugin de dados = plugin "selecionável" usando Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

On my DataTable Jquery, I need to initialize (Using JS / JQuery) manually, the data-plugin = "selectable" plugin. When I add it to the html, everything works correctly, but I need to initialize it manually, using Jquery. Does anyone know how to help me?

Tank you!

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table id="dtFinanceiroParcela" class="table table-striped table-bordered center-header table-vcenter table-responsive-lg" data-plugin="selectable" data-row-selectable="true" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead class="bg-blue-grey-100">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                        <input class="selectable-all" type="checkbox">
                        <label></label>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Parcela
                </th>
                <th>
                    Data de Emissão
                </th>
                <th>
                    Data de Vencimento
                </th>
                <th>
                    Valor da Parcela
                </th>
                <th>
                    Situação
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ações
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to do it like this, but it didn't work:

```
$('#dtFinanceiroParcela').selectable();
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question - but are you looking for the [`select: true`](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/#Initialisation) option? This assumes you have already included the required "select" CSS and JS in your page (from [here](https://datatables.net/download/)).

Comment: Or, are you looking for a way to load those CSS and JS files dynamically? In which case, does something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also) help?

Comment: It would not be referencing CSS or JS. It would be to initialize the plugin, because I'm using ASP.NET core mvc and in my form, I'm setting the Layout to null.

Comment: OK - thank you. I am not sure what you mean by "initialize the plugin", in that case. Perhaps this would mean something to a ASP.NET user. Maybe you should add that tag to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this solution can help other people who have the same problem...
After an exhaustive search on the web, I found the solution to start the plugin:

```
var defaults = Plugin.getDefaults('selectable');
var Switcher = Plugin.getPlugin('selectable');

var dtFinanceiroParcela = $('#dtFinanceiroParcela');
var plugin = new Switcher(dtFinanceiroParcela, defaults);
plugin.initialize();
```