# Why leave mission-critical code to a CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

Here's an example from Bootstrap's "Getting Started" code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Putting CSS and JS onto a CDN seems like pure lunacy. If the CDN goes down, so does your site. I gather that pointing to a CDN gives you the programmer the latest updates and all, but what if the maintainers break their own production code? I always download the necessary css and js and park them in my own directory. Whats the consensus?

**TL;DR** Why leave critical files such as JS and CSS to a CDN?

Comment: Well your "own" CDN can go down too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery) - not specific to your bootstrap example, the the answer there gives numerous reasons for CDN usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reliability is stellar for all three CDNs** *(Google vs. Microsoft vs. Media Temple CDNs)*

*First off, all three CDNs proved to have excellent availability. The only CDN with any downtime at all for this entire year so far was Microsoft’s, and that was just a few minutes. All three had, when rounded to two decimals, **100.00% uptime**.*

*This really is what you want from a CDN. You shouldn’t have to worry about it working or not, and the distributed nature of a CDN usually makes it extremely reliable, as this survey shows.
We will focus the rest of this article on performance since that is where the true differences are.*

[image]

[SOURCE](http://royal.pingdom.com/2012/07/24/best-cdn-for-jquery-in-2012/)

**So the question is. Your host can do better?**

Comment: Ok, that makes ense. But isn't there a significant lag between getting the CSS and JS from a CDN on some distant-ish server versus your own local directory?

Comment: @roguequery not even using a CDN at all? Now that's lunacy. Yes it will do *much* better, that's why CDNs even exist.

Comment: So by that logic, any public-facing site should be backed against some stack like S3->Cloudfront, rather then, as has been admonished before, keeping a whole site on an S3 bucket.

Comment: @loops i made a dupe - simulating discussion none the less

Answer (score 0):

The use of the CDN is to allow for edge caching and improved performance in page loading.  Usually you define a fall back reference in the case the CDN is down.  Here is another answer that describes this process: [How to fallback to local stylesheet (not script) if CDN fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383163/how-to-fallback-to-local-stylesheet-not-script-if-cdn-fails)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose in pointing to a CDN is decidedly **not** to stay up-to-date. Generally, and as it appears in your example, you refer to a particular version of an external script. By doing so, you're protected against buggy releases and breaking changes.

The reason you link to the CDN is twofold: You take load off your own servers, so they can spend their time actually rendering dynamic output. And it decreases load times on your site.

See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn

Regarding downtime: A file hosted on a CDN is far more likely to be available than a file hosted on your own network.