# how to set fall back URL for CSS when css come from cloud or cdn

Tags: javascript, css, cdn, fallback

Hi i use cdn for css  in project

my scripts is loaded successfully but can't load css

so is there any technique to write fall back url in css like javascripts??

Comment: If you're worried about the CDN not correctly distributing the files your best bet may be to host them yourself.

Comment: I think the only solution is js really see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383163/how-to-fallback-to-local-stylesheet-not-script-if-cdn-fails

Comment: Where would your fall back files be hosted? What is that fails?

Comment: It *is* possible that your site might load for a client, but that clients network might block a particular cdn, hence the common sense in using a local backup copy.

Comment: fallback file is on orignal server hosted our site

Answer (score 0):

I like this js plugin to ensure that fallbacks are loaded if required:
http://fallback.io/