# Need to load alternate css if given css is not found

Tags: html

I need to fetch the custom-style_1.css if its found otherwise i need to fetch the custom-style.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/custom-style_1.css"/>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/custom-style.css"/>
```

Comment: I guess [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121273/how-to-check-if-a-stylesheet-is-already-loaded) may help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7452378/5284695

Comment: I tried based on the below site example http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_media_and_alternative_style_sheets_tutorial                                is this possible

Comment: Why don't you load `custom-style.css` first, and then `custom-style_1.css` will override it if it is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch your stylesheet via ajax and return the corresponding link if it succeeds or fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'lib/css/custom-style_1.css',
    success: function() {
        $('head').append('<link  rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/custom-style_1.css" />');
    },
    error: function() {
        $('head').append('<link  rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/custom-style.css" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried based on the below site example http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_media_and_alternative_style_sheets_tutorial                                is this possible

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question. You can set a media attribute on which the stylesheed will be loaded.
You question was to load another stylesheed, if the first one fails to load.

Comment: This could cause CORS problems if the first stylesheet is on another domani.

Comment: You are right, but this depends on the script. Otherwise you have to allow cross-origin resources