# dynamic assets urls (.js and .css files in html document)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html document that contains the following code:

```
...
<head>
  ...
  <link href="//assets.example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//assets.example.com/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

**The context:**

This html document sits in the SPIFFS of a microcontroller. The chip hosts a tiny webserver and can serve static files (like, for instance, this html file). The webserver can be reached either from the internet (automation.example.com) or from my local wifi network (192.168.0.49:1337).

**The problem :**

Reading static files from the chip's memory is very slow (it takes about 7s to get an HTTP 200 from the webserver when I request the self-hosted css).

This is why I moved all the css/js files to my CDN. The response is now lightning fast but I have to consider the case when the internet is down (assets would not load) and I can only reach the chip via my local network.

**The solution :**

I want to load those assets **from my cdn if** the chip is reached from the internet (with absolute urls), or **from the SPIFFS if** the internet is down (with relative urls).

In other words, I'm thinking about the following logic : if the browser's url is an ip or ends with ".local" (multicast dns), do include like this :

```
<link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

otherwise, if the browser url is my domain "example.com", do include like this :

```
<link href="//assets.example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Can you help me with the js code? I can only use client-side code. I believe I am going to need `window.location.hostname` and a few regex but are there more elegant ways of doing this?

So far I've tried this without any great success :

```
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    let hostname = window.location.hostname;
    let cdn = '';

    if ('automation.example.com' === hostname) {
      cdn = '//assets.example.com';
    }

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link href="' + cdn + '/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">');
    head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link href="' + cdn + '/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">');
    head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<script src="' + cdn + '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>');
  </script>
</head>
```

It does not like the "script" insertion part : `Uncaught SyntaxError: '' literal not terminated before end of script`

Maybe I need Promises to avoid flashing of the DOM

Comment: I think this might be the solution you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223674

Comment: @ColdIV Brilliant. That works absolutely great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  ...
  <link id="aaa" href="//assets.example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link id="bbb" href="//assets.example.com/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script id="ccc" src="//assets.example.com/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let hostname = window.location.hostname;
    let cdn = ''; // SPIFFS

    if ('automation.example.com' === hostname) {
      cdn = '//assets.example.com';
    }

    // bootstrap.min.css
    let aaa = document.getElementById('aaa');
    aaa.href = cdn + '/css/bootstrap.min.css';

    // login.css
    let bbb = document.getElementById('bbb');
    bbb.href = cdn + '/css/login.css';

    // bootstrap.bundle.min.js
    let ccc = document.getElementById('ccc');
    ccc.src = cdn + '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
  </script>
</head>
```

This works but I am seeking a more elegant solution. It tries to load the assets from the cdn no matter the context (internet/local network). If we have internet, it will request the files twice, which is not a big deal as they are cached. If we do not have internet, it will load from the chip's file system.

Edit: see @ColdIV 's comment for the solution.