# onerror this.src not working when I try to fetch local js file if CDN fails

Tags: javascript, failover

I try to apply this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383163/how-to-fallback-to-local-stylesheet-not-script-if-cdn-fails/52223674#52223674) with JS but not working to fetch local js file if CDN fails, and i don't know why

```
<script src="cdn.js" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='local.js';"></script>
```

this way only work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.js" 
    onerror="this.onerror=null;document.write('<script type=text/javascript src=local.js></script>');"></script>
```