# Losing style with load jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've a page with this format:

```
<div id="index" data-role="page">
     <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

And I load into #container the content of the page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').load("pages/content.html");
 }); 
</script>
```

And "pages/content.html" has this content:

```
<div data-role="content">

    <a href="pages/calendar.html" data-role="button">Calendar</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that the button does not come with the style of jquery mobile .. I tried to do. trigger ('create') but without success.

Any Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195287/losing-css-after-jquery-ajax-load

Comment: can you show how you have tried using trigger('create')??

Comment: After load function - $('#container').trigger('create');

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').html('<div data-role="content"><a href="pages/calendar.html" data-role="button">Calendar</a></div>');
    $('#container').trigger('create');
 }); ​
```

Swap the `.html` for your `.load` code. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMG85/): If you comment out the `$('#container').trigger('create');` the link will remain unformatted.