# Load StyleSheet dynamically with Callback function

Tags: javascript, css

I have this short JavaScript function that loads CSS file dynamically. But im not yet good at JavaScript so can anyone give me an idea on how can I create a callback function once the CSS file was successfully loaded...

```
function loadStyleSheet(url){
    if(document.createStyleSheet) {
        try {document.createStyleSheet(url);} catch (e) { }
    }
    else{
        var css;
        css         = document.createElement('link');
        css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
        css.type    = 'text/css';
        css.media   = "all";
        css.href    = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
    }
}
```

P.S. If you have an idea on how I can also know if the loading of CSS file has failed. Well i will thank you more ^_^

Comment: the original codes came from here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805384/how-to-apply-inline-and-or-external-css-loaded-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: I have tested this on IE7,8,9 FF, Safari, Opera and Chrome this code is nicely working...

Comment: Is the CSS loaded from same domain or some other domain?

Comment: outside of the domain...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is a bullet proof way to check if the style sheet is loaded. It primarily depends on whether the CSS is loaded from same domain or another.

The trick I used to check whether a CSS has loaded is to add (or use) a known rule in CSS as follows:

- Example rule: `.foobar { display: none; }`
- Add an element in my document: `<span class="foobar"></span>`
- Load the CSS using the method you used
- Poll the document at regular intervals using `window.setTimeout()` and check whether `span.foobar` is still visible. When it is hidden it would mean the CSS has loaded

Comment: im thinking that i gonna create a hidden div that will be manipulated by the CSS file. if the hidden div was manipulated... then the CSS was loaded

Comment: My point exactly. For external domain CSS, AJAX is not an option; `document.styleSheets[n].cssRules.length > 0` is also not an option.

Comment: Hope this can rise to the top :)  it's the only answer I see here that actually addresses the original question

Answer (score 1):

Pass the callback function in as an argument to your function, then call it after  you have loaded your stylesheet.

For example:

```
function myFunc() {
  alert("Hello, World");
}

loadStyleSheet("link/to/stylesheet.css", myFunc);

function loadStyleSheet(url, callback){
    if(document.createStyleSheet) {
        try {document.createStyleSheet(url);} catch (e) { }
    }
    else{
        var css;
        css         = document.createElement('link');
        css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
        css.type    = 'text/css';
        css.media   = "all";
        css.href    = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
    }
    callback();
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to test whether it has loaded the stylesheet properly, you will have to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: how can i detect if the css file is successfully loaded? i know this code will work... but what if there was a timeout and the css file was not loaded

Comment: You'll have to use AJAX for that.  I would recommend learning jQuery as it makes this a lot easier to understand and implement.

Comment: Is there any link that you can give me about loading a CSS file using AJAX with callback function?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I'm sure you can find something like that with Google pretty easily.  As I said, it'll be much easier with jQuery.

Comment: You can add a load handler to `css` without going to AJAX; the problem remains the IE proprietary stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer to my problem ^_^
http://yepnopejs.com/

thank you everyone for your help ^_^

Answer (score -2):

I think the simplest would be to append the markup to the head on load

```
$('<link rel="stylesheet" href="link.css" type="text/css" />').appendTo("head")
.each(function() { //little trick to create the callback function
    // I am the callback
});
```

<sup>**P.S: Its a jQuery solution. I didn't notice JS & CSS tag, but still its a good solution**</sup>

Comment: Doesn't this also not mean "load" but instead on append to the DOM?  I think the original question is referring to CSS having been loaded and parsed, not that you've created the `<link />` element