# Using Javascript to detect if font is installed, then serve different css if it's not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, embedded-fonts

I'm new to Javascript (but not HTML or CSS) and am trying to use this script by [Lalit Patel](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/) to detect whether a font is installed on the user's system, and if not, to serve a modified style sheet. I've been successful in getting the first part to work: I uploaded the fontdetect.js file, called it in my header, then pasted this before the end of my body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var detective = new Detector();
    alert(detective.detect('Courier'));
};
</script>
```

(With Courier used as an example.) This causes an alert to pop up on page load telling me whether a font is installed, and works beautifully. But I don't know how to get the script to, instead of triggering an alert, grab a different stylesheet. This seems like basic stuff but I just can't find the specifics anywhere, even though I've been plowing through Javascript tutorials. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If any more specifics are needed: If a user doesn't have the custom font installed or has custom fonts turned off entirely, I'd like to, using CSS change the size/spacing properties of the text so that the fallback font is able to fit in the same space.

Comment: have you checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805384/how-to-apply-inline-and-or-external-css-loaded-dynamically-with-jquery) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685614/load-external-css-file-like-scripts-in-jquery-which-is-compatible-in-ie-also)?

Comment: I hadn't seen those, good starting place, thanks!

Comment: @Rohrbs: both of those rely on jQuery, yet OP doesn't mention or tag the library...

Comment: @BradChristie It's a comment. They probably should've mentioned it used jQuery, but it's not any less valid as a comment

Comment: @BradChristie True. I did notice the OP didn't mention jQuery, but thought those SO Q's would get them on the right track. Regardless, kudos on the pure JS answer. :)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I do have jQuery installed, although I am still JS 101 so pure JS is easier to wrap my head around. I do appreciate the links though (and have updated the tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all the methods presented, this is the one that worked for me (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754995/1958539), but it's really a mix of the two answers presented here). It should be noted that this works in IE8, unlike most of the other methods (sadly I do need IE8 compatibility).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var detective = new Detector();
        if (!detective.detect('Meat')){
            var url = 'link/to/style.css'
            if(document.createStyleSheet) {
                try { document.createStyleSheet(url); } catch (e) { }
            }
            else {
                var css;
                css         = document.createElement('link');
                css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
                css.type    = 'text/css';
                css.media   = "all";
                css.href    = url;
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

This detected that my browser wasn't accepting embedded fonts ("Meat" being one of the fonts I embedded) and served up the alternate CSS (although with a slight delay/flash of unstyled text, maybe because it's at the bottom of the page?) Anyhow, thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
var detective = new Detector();
if (!detective.detect('Courier')){
  var s = document.createElement('link');
  s.rel = 'stylesheet';
  s.type = 'text/css';
  s.media = 'all';
  s.href = '/link/to/alternative/stylesheet.css';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Guessing something like that. if `.detect()` fails, it will dynamically create and insert a stylesheet in to the page. If you encounter problems, you can also use [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) off of the `s` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to add a stylesheet to the website:

```
var detective = new Detector();

if (!detective.detect('Courier')){    
     document.createStyleSheet('location/stylesheet.css');
}
else
{
     document.createStyleSheet('location/otherstylesheet.css');
}
```

So you could do a check to see if the Dectector returns true, if not load one style, if it does then load the other.

Comment: to my knowledge, [`createStyleSheet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is only valid in IE.

Comment: @BradChristie doesn't work at all now in IE11: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531194

Comment: @carefulnow That's a good thing, they're standardizing; Nothing worse than a unique IE api.

Comment: @BradChristie really? But everyone *loved* doing everything ActiveX!