# Load css without importing it

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, is there any convention that would allow a style sheet of a page to be used **witout** using a `link` or `import` from that page?

Comment: Can you use Javascript for this?

Comment: What would be a potential use case for such a convention?

Comment: What would be the benefit of this? The key negative being the fact that the CSS data wouldn't be cached as it would in a separate file and wouldn't even load until after the HTML was finished loading if you imported it via JavaScript.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/805406/1470950

Comment: @MarcelGwerder:I believe I saw such a page and can not figure out how it works.Unfortunately I don't have the page available at the moment

Comment: Even the javascript solutions are just inserting `link` or `style` tags into the page.

Comment: So I'm tempted to agree that @MarcelGwerder is on the right track. What's the point? What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: This isn't a bad question.

Comment: @BenLee:Trying to understand existing code.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `style` tags in the page (preferably in the `head`):

```
<style>

    /* CSS declarations here */

</style>
```

Comment: HTML5 spec says `<style>` tags are ok in the body as well, but yes, head tag is preferred. is `type="text/css"` required pre-HTML5?

Comment: I am asking about an external style sheet. Not internal.

Comment: Omitting the type is not permitted in HTML4.01

Comment: @Jim Then no. You would have to either add a `link` tag via JavaScript or add the `style` tags as I mentioned (via JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
Here is the simplest thing I could came with:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '#element{color:red}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

THis will dinamically create a style element and appendit to the head.
Of course you could do better if you want to use the CSSOM methods like addRule.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekmyR/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you would still use link but not directly from the page.

You could put this in an external javascript file that should be loaded with the page (using jQuery):

```
$('head').append($("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<FILE.CSS>'/>"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This still ends up putting a <link> tag into the code so it doesn't seem like this is what the questioner is asking.