# How to include CSS for a specific part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website, the users have to enter markdown in a textarea, for which I am using [a markdown editor](https://github.com/lepture/editor). The problem is: it uses icomoon font, and my websites too. Both uses the same class to define the fonts, but not both uses the same icons. The question is simple: is there a way to define the `editor.css` for a special div?

Like that:

```
<div css="editor.css"></div>
```

Comment: There will be, in a couple of years, with [scoped style tags](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/) ?

Comment: The answer, something (a class/selector) has to change. You pick.

Comment: @schnawel007 has the best answer yet.  Use that as a starting point and see if you can complete it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Namespace your editor styles

You can add a selector that namespaces your editor and allows you to style it:

```
<div class="editor-style">
  <div id="cool-custom-editor">...</div>
</div>
```

In your css:

```
.editor-style .icon-thumbs-up { color: green; }
```

### Using Scoped Styles (needs polyfill)

As mentioned in @adeneo's comment below your question there is the option of using **scoped style** tags.

Supposing your editor looks like this:

```
<div id="cool-custom-editor">...</div>
```

You can apply a specific style using the `scoped` attribute like so:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>@import url(editor.css);</style>
  <div id="cool-custom-editor">...</div>
<div>
```

#### Caveats

[According to can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped) the `scoped` attribute is only natively supported by Firefox 26+.

If you want to use it you will have to polyfill:

- [Plain JavaScript polyfill](https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill)
- [jQuery scoped plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin)

#### Further Reading

- [HTML5 Doctor - The scoped attribute](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/)
- [CSSTricks - Saving the day with scoped styles](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/)
- [HTML5Rocks - A new experimental feature - Scoped Styles](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/A-New-Experimental-Feature-style-scoped)

Answer (score 3):

Give the DIV a Class and then add a CSS file like this:

```
.markdown
{
color: red;
}
```

If you import a new css dynamic, the old styles will be overwritten.

Some help, for dynamic css loading: [How to apply inline and/or external CSS loaded dynamically with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805384/how-to-apply-inline-and-or-external-css-loaded-dynamically-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need multiple files. You can give the div an id or class like so

```
  <div class="div1">
      <span></span
    ...
  </div>
```

and  now in you css you do this

```
   .div1 span{
        font:(whatever font);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, no. At least not without using any js workarounds. The best solution would be to use kind of namespace for user-specific css classes.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that.. I think you should solve the conflit by changing the icomoon class names in this file.

Answer (score 0):

OK solved: renaming the classes in editor for icomoon was a lot easier than I dared tough.

Answer (score 0):

not a good way but it can help:

```
$("[css]").each(function(i){
    var elm = $(this);
    $.when($.get(elm.attr("css"))).done(function(response) {
        var newresponse=response.replace(/(.+{)/gi,".customCss"+i+" $1");
        elm.addClass("customCss"+i);
        elm.before('<style>'+newresponse+'</style>');
    });
});
```