# How can I Load external Css files Using jquery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am sending AJAX request after 10 seconds  to get  the  data  from Nodejs Server but i keep receiving that  resources interpreted as  Style sheet and  converted to mime-type html/css .  Server is returning   text/html .  code works fine   but  external css dosnt work .  the following code works fine  for me  functionality wise  but i want to load external css files

My code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/jrt/?Id=$data.jet.id',
            method: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                //$("#gt").append(data);
                $('#gt').html(data);
                if (state == 'jr' || state == 'jt')
                {
                    window.clearTimeout(timer);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply inline and/or external CSS loaded dynamically with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805384/how-to-apply-inline-and-or-external-css-loaded-dynamically-with-jquery)

Comment: This may help you - https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-get-the-css-to-load-in-the-nodejs-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944#answer-577002) answer. It seems to just by javascript.

This code creates an id that checks if it already exists with the if statement the `link.id`. It then creates a `<link></link>`, then adds all the attributes.

```
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Untested, but maybe this would work:

```
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var $head  = $('head');
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.attr({
        id:cssId, 
        rel:'stylesheet',
        type:'text/css',
        href:'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css', 
        media:'all'
    });
    $head.append(link);
}
```