# Dynamically adding media queries to the page and overriding the styles from generated html from Application Side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, media-queries

I have code where i dynamically add custom css to my html on the application side like this:

C# code:

```
html = html + string.Format("<div id='{0}' class='sectioncon SectionComp 
responsiveSectionClass_{0}'>", sectionGUID);
```

This html variable gets returned to the UI and i then use (someselector).append(html)

Then client side i retrieve this information and spit out the media query using jquery like this:

Jquery code:

```
var stylesheetXS = $("<style id='" + this.responsiveClass + "'>")

var txtAll = "";
txtAll += "@@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {";
txtAll += "." + this.responsiveClass;
txtAll += "{";
txtAll += this.Style;
txtAll += "}";
txtAll += "}";

$(stylesheetXS).html(txtAll);

$("head").append(stylesheetXS);
```

So this.responsiveClass is the reference to responsiveSectionClass_{0} where {0} is a GUID.

The Jquery code gets added first before the c# code gets appended to the UI, so why is my Dynamically generated Media query not taking affect to the class in the html code?

Also when i select the element using chrome developer tool i cant see the media query that has been generated thats why i think that im doing something wrong here.

This is the generated html or part of it:

Media Query:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {.responsiveSectionClass_d7099673a3924894bec0bdb59f6ad0b0{padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;width:auto;height:auto;}}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sectioncon SectionComp responsiveSectionClass_d7099673a3924894bec0bdb59f6ad0b0" style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;width:auto;height:auto;"></div>
```

This is all i see in the code inspector:

```
element.style {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.sectioncon {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

To Nathans response i tried this:

```
var txtAll = "";
                txtAll += "@@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {";
                txtAll += "." + this.responsiveClassXS;
                txtAll += "{";
                txtAll += this.Style;
                txtAll += "}";
                txtAll += "}";

                var css;
                css = document.createElement("style");
                css.id = this.responsiveClassXS
                css.type = 'text/css';
                css.media = "all";
                css.textContent = txtAll;
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
```

but still not recognising the media query.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that in the question, i have updated

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805384/how-to-apply-inline-and-or-external-css-loaded-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: Apologies, the content or media query needed to be applied inside an iframe, should i delete this question?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to talk to the interior of an iframe from the parent document. The content being loaded in the iframe will have to handle its own styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I can't get it to work in a stack snippet, but you can view a live demo [here](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/gObGeZx) (or just save the code below as .html file and open it in a browser..) I made the background blue so that it would stand out more..

Here is a video of this working:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script>
    let iframeEl = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeEl.setAttribute("style", "height: 100%; width: 100%;");
    document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);
    iframeEl.contentDocument.open();
    iframeEl.contentDocument.write('<div class="sectioncon SectionComp responsiveSectionClass_d7099673a3924894bec0bdb59f6ad0b0" style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;width:auto;height:auto;"></div>');
    iframeEl.contentDocument.close();
    let styleSheet = `
        @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
            .responsiveSectionClass_d7099673a3924894bec0bdb59f6ad0b0 {
                padding-top: 30px;
                padding-bottom:30px;
                width:auto;
                height:auto;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }`;
    let style = '<style type="text/css">' + styleSheet + "</style>";
    iframeEl.contentDocument.head.innerHTML += style;
</script>

</html>
```